# Select 10 records after id=somevalue, (id>somevalue) and select first 10 records if id=somevalue doesn't exist

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have an sql query which selects 10 records after id= somevalue, but i want to select the first 10 records if the record doesnt exist. Query is in below structure.

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE ID > x ORDER BY METRIC LIMIT 10
```

Provided, id here is a varchar field which is sorted based on some field.

Comment: What if there are not 10 records after the id?

Comment: Need to get what ever remaining.

Answer (score 1):

This comes close to what you want:

```
SELECT *
FROM TABLE
ORDER BY (CASE WHEN ID > X THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) DESC,
         METRIC
LIMIT 10
```

It will always return 10 records (assuming you have at least 10 records in the table).  It will put the ones with `id > x` first.  If there are not enough of those, then it will fill in with other records.

Comment: But in my case id is a varchar field. It is sorted based on some metric and i want next 10 records after the given id value or return first 10 if the given id doen't exist

Answer (score -1):

This will also work:

```
SELECT TOP 10 col1, col2
FROM #yourtable
WHERE col1 > @ID
UNION ALL
SELECT TOP 10 col1, col2
FROM #yourtable
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM #yourtable WHERE col1 = @ID)
```

However, this assumes you have an ID that you can query on using greater than/less than to retrieve the desired "next ten" records. Also, you would probably need to add an "ORDER BY" clause to ensure the records have the desired values.

Comment: That looks like SQL Server syntax to me, not PostgreSQL.